# Validation on multiple Inputs via Jquery

Tags: jquery

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I can set up 2 independant inputs with a single submit button.

I have 2 input elements. Each element will post a different element id back. 
Each input will validate its input seperatly. i.e show its own error message.

My code looks like this

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    $("#input-whatmask").click(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(){
    $(".error").hide();
    $("#input-whois").removeClass("errorinput");
    var hasError = false;
        var searchReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\/\.]+$/;
        var searchVal = $("#input-whatmask").val();

        if(searchVal == '') {
            $("#input-whatmask").addClass("errorinput");
        $("#input-whatmask").after('<span class="error">Enter an IP and mask.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if(!searchReg.test(searchVal)) {
        $("#input-whatmask").addClass("errorinput");
        $("#input-whatmask").after('<span class="error">Enter valid text.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        }
        if(hasError == true) {return false;}
                                else {
                                        return true;
                                }
    });
});
});
jQuery(function(){
        $("#input-whois").click(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(){
        $(".error").hide();
    $("#input-whatmask").removeClass("errorinput");
    var hasError = false;
        var searchReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\/\.]+$/;
        var searchVal = $("#input-whois").val();

        if(searchVal == '') {
            $("#input-whois").addClass("errorinput");
        $("#input-whois").after('<span class="error">Enter an IP address or domain.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if(!searchReg.test(searchVal)) {
            $("#input-whois").addClass("errorinput");
        $("#input-whois").after('<span class="error">Enter valid text.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        }
        if(hasError == true) {return false;}
                                else {
                                        return true;
                                }
    });
});
});


</script>

<form method="post" name="form1" action="/whatmask_output/">
{% csrf_token %}
          <div id="sectioncol" ><span class="section" >whatmask</span><input type="text" name="input-whatmask" id="input-whatmask" value="" size="20" /></div>
      <br/><br/>
      <div id="sectioncol" ><span class="section" >whois</span><input type="text" name="input-whois" id="input-whois" value="" size="20" /></div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn-search" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are the few methods you tried.please show us the code.

Comment: what do you want? Validate 2 input elements? Submit a form?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the JQuery Validation plugin? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: `<form><input id="one"/><input id="two"/><input type="submit"/><form>`

Comment: @Rocket when OP said `2 independant inputs` I'd assume they were not in the same form. :P

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: The OP really didn't give any details at all.

Comment: You're right there. OP provide us some code so we can look on that.

Comment: How do I add an additional comment with code. Ive amended the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hasError = false;

    $("form").submit(function(e){
        var searchReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\/\.]+$/;

        if ($("#input-whatmask").val() != '' && $("#input-whois").val() != '')
        {
            alert('Enter only one field at a time!');
            return false;
        }

        if (hasError)
            return false;

        if ($("#input-whatmask").val() != '')
        {
            if(!searchReg.test($("#input-whatmask").val())){
                $("#input-whatmask").addClass("errorinput").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid value.</span>');
                hasError = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if ($("#input-whois").val() != '')
        {
            if(!searchReg.test($("#input-whois").val())){
                $("#input-whois").addClass("errorinput").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid value.</span>');
                hasError = true;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert('No values entered!');
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#input-whatmask, #input-whois").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('errorinput'))
        {
            $(this).next().remove();
            $(this).removeClass("errorinput");
            hasError = false;
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/dQJv7/8/)

Comment: Thanks, the code looks much simplier but now both boxes show the validation error and also the validation error is repeated if multiple validation errors occur.

Comment: Yes, I made it validate both boxes as you asked. Be specific on what errors you'd like to display and when to display, edit it in your question so I can tweak my answer.

Comment: I removed the duplicate errors and made it stop validating after the first error, check if this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/dQJv7/3/) is what you want

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Ive update the main question slighty. The main issue with this at present is that it shows an error on input A if there is an validation error on input B. Also if the input for input A is fine but input B is not then an error is shown.

Comment: I don't get it. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/dQJv7/7/) again, if there's an error in input A it'll only display an error in input A. Same for input B. And if there are errors in both inputs, it'll stop validating after the first error. Or did you want to validate only 1 of them?

Comment: Ive checked and if I put input into input B (that is not valid) the error shows againest input A (??). My main goal is to only validate 1 at a time. So if the user is clicked on input B and they enter a value then that is validated. Once the user clicks on input A then the input B error is removed and the input A validation is done. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Oh guess I see what you mean, right now it validates to don't accept any empty field. Did you want to validate to only have 1 field with text?

Comment: Yep ideally I need to only validate the single input box while a user is clicked on it. Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: I updated the fiddle. I'm still not sure about what you want exactly, but check this >> [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/dQJv7/8/). It accepts entering only 1 field at a time and validates it, most likely not the best approach but check if it's closer to what you want.

Comment: hey, this looks loads better. Thanks for all your help.